# Make temporary backup files in the same folder structure

Tags: powershell

Below is a full path to some files that have a specific file pattern I'm looking for. The files are not all located in the same location, however, I would like to change the ".gen" to ".tmp" for a short period of time while still maintaining ".gen" in its entirety.

```
D:\Example\CommonData\Settings\ConnectionSettings.config.gen 
D:\Example\CommonData\Settings\FileExtensions.config.gen
D:\Example\WebApps\Website\Web.config.gen
D:\Example\Test\SCM\Config.Files\Some.Other.thing.config.gen
```

What I would like to do:

```
D:\Example\CommonData\Settings\ConnectionSettings.config.gen
D:\Example\CommonData\Settings\ConnectionSettings.config.tmp 
D:\Example\CommonData\Settings\FileExtensions.config.gen
D:\Example\CommonData\Settings\FileExtensions.config.tmp
D:\Example\WebApps\Website\Web.config.gen
D:\Example\WebApps\Website\Web.config.tmp
D:\Example\Test\SCM\Config.Files\Some.Other.thing.config.gen
D:\Example\Test\SCM\Config.Files\Some.Other.thing.config.tmp
```

I've tried so far:

```
Get-ChildItem *.config.gen | ForEach {
  $NewName = $_.Name -replace ".config.gen$", ".config.tmp"
  Copy-Item $_ $NewName
}
```

Is what I'm trying to do more easier to do with `xcopy` or `robocopy` versus `Copy-Item`? If so, how would I go about using something other than `Copy-Item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the destination items renamed `Get-ChildItem`/`Copy-Item` is the better approach here. Something like this should work:

```
Get-ChildItem *.config.gen -Recurse |
  Copy-Item -Destination { Join-Path $_.Directory ($_.BaseName + '.tmp') }
```

Comment: Thanks again! That's exactly what I was looking for!